# Rotating To Face a Point

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, mouse

I am trying to rotate a line to point to the mouse's world coordinates (rather where the mouse lies on the plane where y=0).

I am running into a couple of problems though:

- Whilst it follows the mouse the line doesn't always lie directly beneath the cursor, which is what I would expect to see. It seems to be perfect when the position is at the origin and less accurate the further away from the origin I get.
- The rotation doesn't go from 0 - 360, rather 0 - 180. I think the solution here is to use a dot product but the first problem is preventing me from fixing this problem.

Here's where I calculate the angle by which to rotate:

Calculating mouse position

```
 Vector3 near, far, dir;
 unproject(*mouse_, near, far);
 dir = near - far;
 normalize(dir);

 float t = -near.y / dir.y;
 Vector3 point = near + (t * dir); //where the mouse lies on the plane y=0
```

I'm almost certain the above is correct as when I draw a point at `point` the rendered point is directly beneath the cursor on the plane y=0

Calculating angle between the line and the point.

```
 rotation_.y = angleBetween(position_ - dir_, position_ - point);
 rotation_.y = radToDeg(rotation_.y);
```

`position_` is where I want the line to start from. Which is the player's position at the moment.
`dir_` is the direction of the line, set to and never changed `Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f);`

```
 float angleBetween(const Vector3& a, const Vector3& b) {
     float cosTheta = dot(a, b) / (length(a) * length(b));

     return acos(cosTheta);
 }
```

Here's how I am drawing the line:

```
 glPushMatrix();
 glTranslatef(position_.x, position_.y, position_.z);
 glRotatef(rotation_.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
 glRotatef(rotation_.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
 glRotatef(rotation_.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

 glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
 glLineWidth(3.0f);
 glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
 glBegin(GL_LINES);

 glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
 glVertex3fv(end_.toArray().data()); //toArray() returns and std::array of the vector

 glEnd();
 glPopMatrix();
```

And just in case it matters, for the camera I do:

```
void Camera::transform() {
    gluLookAt(position_.x, position_.y, position_.z,
              target_.x, target_.y, target_.z,
              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

`target_` is also the player's position.

I hope this is enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding this bit of code:

```
rotation_.y = angleBetween(position_ - dir_, position_ - point);
rotation_.y = radToDeg(rotation_.y);
```

First of all, if `dir_` is truly a direction vector, it shouldn't be subtracted from the position, so you'd just call `angleBetween(dir_, point - position_);`.  (I reversed the subtraction in the second argument so that it's calculating the vector *from* `position_` *to* `point`, which I think is what you wanted.)

Second, the way you want to calculate the angle between these vectors is probably something like `atan2(b.x, b.z) - atan2(a.x, a.z)` rather than the method you used.  As you noted, the acos(dot product) method will always pick the shortest distance around the circle and give a positive angle; the atan2 method should give a correctly-signed result so that you'll rotate either clockwise or anticlockwise as appropriate.  Also, this will automatically project things into the XZ plane, which is appropriate since you're always going to be rotating around the Y axis.  (The dot product version of `angleBetween` will give an angle around whatever axis is perpendicular to the two vectors, which won't be the Y axis if either vector has a nonzero Y component.)

Comment: Aha, thank you. I was getting close to solution with my scribbling. I realise what I was doing now, thank you. I will try using `atan2`  for the angle now.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but does `atan2` give the rotation around whatever axis is ommited from the calculation? I.e in your example y was ommited and it gave the angle on the y axis?

Comment: @Lerp Yes, that's right.  In 2D, `atan2(y, x)` gives the angle from the +X axis, going counterclockwise around the origin.  In 3D, I just changed y, x to x, z to account for the fact you're using Y as up and XZ is the "ground" plane.